# d3.js radial line counterclockwise

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to draw the radial line in this example counterclockwise in order to have the arc on top/ in the upper-half?

http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5431779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible (but working) solution: set the radius the negative value.

> arc.radius(-xdist / 2);

Answer (score 0):

You'll obviously have to make several changes to the example to rearrange the nodes, but the easiest way to reverse the direction of the arc is to change the range.

Existing code:

```
// scale to generate radians (just for lower-half of circle)
var radians = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([Math.PI / 2, 3 * Math.PI / 2]);
```

Modified version:

```
// scale to generate radians (just for upper-half of circle)
var radians = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2]);
```